# tabEndNewRow copies first fow instead of using provided data

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In my code I pass to `tabEndNewRow` an intial empty row object. When you go to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/Lkah397y/17/) and enter something to C2 column and hit `tab` key then

- new row is inserted - correct
- entered value is assigned to C2 column of new row - error

if you use function for `tabEndNewRow` then it works as expected. Did I get it wrong?

```js
var cols = [
    { title: "Cell 1", field: "c1" },
    { title: "Cell 2", field: "c2", editor: "input" }
];
        
var row = {"c1":"","c2":""}

var table = new Tabulator('#table', {
    columns: cols,
    data: [row],
    height:"100%",
    tabEndNewRow: row,
});
```

[Tabulator](http://tabulator.info) v5.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS Fiddle, you are passing the row object into both the `data` optionand the `tabEndNewRow` option.

Because objects are passed by reference, edits to the row data are then stored in that same object which is called when the new row is created, so it is populated by the new data.

In your example you need to break the reference by calling `Object.assign` when passing the row object to the `tabEndNewRow` prop:

```js
tabEndNewRow:Object.assign({}, row);
```

Comment: but the row data object edits Tabulator, right?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean?

Comment: thanks to you I know how to use a variable to set tabEndNewRow. But I cannot see that I or "my" code would modify variable row.

Comment: Tabulator does when the used edits the cell on the row and because it is passed by reference it will affect the new row that you pass in if it is the same object